# Is this technique bad practice?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I notice in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nGAwLwfA0gQ&t=648s

the artist is using multiple meshes to make an object instead of carving it out of one mesh. This means that there are internal/conflicting faces.

Is the method the artist is using bad practice? Should they have carved everything out of one single mesh by extruding and modifying vertices/edges?

Comment: Whether it's bad practice depends on what you want to do with it.  How do you want to render it?  Do you want to use for booleans?  Do you want to edge line it?  Do you want to use CC subdivision?  Do you want to use the meshes for physics?  There is no such thing as a general bad practice; there is only, not going to be able to handle problem x in the way you want.  But if you don't need to do x?  Then do whatever gets you your picture fastest.  Voting to close on "needs more info" because somebody's going to vote to close on "opinion based" and it's not opinion, it just depends on things.

Comment: Got it, thank you for the feedback. Can you help me understand a situation where this WOULD be bad practice? What problems could arise from modeling this way?

Comment: Sure, to *a* situation.  If you draw an extruded hull edge line, you won't get an edge line on intersecting planes.  You want *all* possible problems that can arise?  Sorry, I can't do that.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos sorry and thank you. I'll make sure any future questions are better formed.

Comment: @Nathan thank you.